# been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, cors

I have a login API using .net core 2.2, that suddenly returned this error:
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://hostname/users/authenticate' from origin 'https://domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' **header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.**

at first I got this error:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

then in web.config i put **"add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" "** like the full code below:

**then i got a new error** that I asked about in this post " header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, Accept"/>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Https ApiLogin Page"  stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDavModule" />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

this is my: [header Request](https://ibb.co/3sxdZpM)
this is my: [Startup.cs](https://ibb.co/KXdNCB9)

what i need to do to fix the **"header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed."**?

Comment: To fix _"**header** contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed"_ error, you need to fix **header** of your request. Can you show it?

Comment: do you mean this? [link](https://ibb.co/3sxdZpM)

Answer (score 1):

you have to add Core Policy in your api

put this on top of your controller

`[EnableCors("SiteCorsPolicy")]`

and this in your StartUp.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(opts =>
        {
            opts.AddPolicy(
          name: ConstantPolicies.DynamicPermission,
          configurePolicy: policy =>
          {
              policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
              policy.Requirements.Add(new DynamicPermissionRequirement());
          });
        });
```

Comment: i put on top of controller, bat where in Startup.cs?

Comment: In ConfigureServices method. your startup seems ok. you're getting this error yet?

Comment: And I do not understand why, I tried so many things that I was suggest and there's still a problem, I'm sure I'm missing something :(

Comment: undo your web.config and test again

Comment: I tried that too, **when del from web.config** and left with only the code in Startup.cs i have got the first **error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**